# Retrieving a random item out of an array within a dictionary in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, arc4random

I have been trying to crack this for months and have finally gotten to the point where I feel that I need to ask for help.

Ultimately I am trying to randomise the key which is returned from my dictionary and then randomise the value returned from its values.

My dictionary is:

```
var kbDirectory: [String: [String]] = ["Squat": ["4 x 10", "3 x 15", "3 x 20"],
                                   "Deadlift": ["4 x 10", "3 x 15", "3 x 20"],
                                   "2 Handed Swing":["4 x 10", "3 x 15", "3 x 20"],
                                   "Press Up":["4 x 10", "3 x 15", "3 x 20"],
                                   "Pull up":["4 x 10", "3 x 15", "3 x 20"]]
```

I've attempted multiple times and tried learning from various sources but cannot seem to get it right. Any answers or being pointed in the right direction of what to search/learn would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Don't hesitate to show your attempts, so that we can see where your problems are and help accordingly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(kbDirectory.count)))
let dictValues = Array(kbDirectory.values)
let randomArray = dictValues[randomIndex]
let randomArrayIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(randomArray.count)))
let randomValue = randomArray[randomArrayIndex]
```